# Local Notification 15 Minute Interval Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

I am trying to embed local notification in my code which i want to get repeat after every 15 minutes. It takes NsCalendarUnit and i am unable to figure out as in how to convert 15 mints into NSCalendarUnit

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:30];
localNotification.repeatInterval = 900.0;
localNotification.alertBody = @"Your alert message";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `repeatInterval` is not a time, it an value of [`NSCalendarUnit`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendarunit).

This means you can *NOT* set the interval to 15 min.

You best option is to use 4 notification with a `repeatInterval` of `NSCalendarUnitHour` and set them 15 minutes apart.